# Connecting client to server using Socket.io in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, socket.io, spring-websocket, java-websocket

how can i Connecting client to server using Socket.io and using Java.

I have read this documentation, but unfortunately there are no examples written in Java

Comment: Try these https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/initialization.html & https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-server-java/using.html